# Using computer as external hardrive "flashdrive" for xbox360 slim?

Tags: windows-8, xbox360

Anyone know if it's possible to connect your computer to your xbox 360 slim using it as a 'flash-drive' to stream games. I've installed grand theft auto 5 on a thumb drive but don't have enough space for everything, & my xbox's hard drive is a 4gb drive with 3.2 gb available. I need about 18gb of space & I'm running just under that.

If it's possible anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more than likely not going to be possible in the way you think it might work. Accessing the HDD of your computer as if it were a USB device isn't going to be possible.

However, the Xbox360 can allocate up to 32GB of space on an external USB device, such as a flash drive or an external hard drive. You can allocate this space using the built in storage management settings on the Xbox360 by going to `Settings > System Settings > Memory or Storage`.

The only part I'm not sure of is if the entire drive needs to be formatted before it can allocate it's required space.

http://support.xbox.com/en-NZ/xbox-360/accessories/usb-flash-drive

http://support.xbox.com/en-NZ/xbox-360/accessories/storage